# How to modify Security group name for a AWS Security Group

Tags: amazon-web-services

How to modify Security group name for a AWS Security Group, it shows as "launch-wizard" by default. Not sure how to change this value

Comment: Just change in tags. The tag is called "Name".

Comment: It cannot be changed. See linked answer.